# Problem with ExpandableListView position

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a "Dynamic" ExpandableListView. That is to say child are only load when there is click on there parent.

So  I use `onGroupExpand` to load list. It works but I must expand myself the group with

```
expandableList.expandGroup(groupPosition);
```

The problem is that, when I click on parent, the group expands but the view go back to the first position. That is to say : I scroll, I click on parent, group expand, view go back to the first parent, so I must scroll again to see the group I click before.

I try to use `expandableList.scrollTo(x,y);` But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the scrolling problem? I am having a similar issue ...

Comment: No I didn't. Nonce, I work on something that more important for my application. If you find any solution could you write it here Please ?
If I find, I will put it here.

Comment: Try that: listView.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am having a similar problem. I found this method that lets you scroll based on an item position :

```
mList.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
```

The downside is I have to call this from my groupClickListener() and in order to get it to work I have to put it inside of a runnable and delay it by part of a second otherwise it will do nothing. This means my list scrolls one way then stops and scrolls back to where it was, which looks weird. But its the only thing I've come up with thus far.

Comment: yes, I found the same, i forget to post the solution. Thank's to do it.

Comment: Why does it have to be called from a Runnable?